# How to convert configure options for use with cmake

Tags: cmake, configure

I have a script for building a project that I need to upgrade from using configure to cmake. The original configure command is

```
CFLAGS="$SLKCFLAGS" \
CXXFLAGS="$SLKCFLAGS" \
./configure \
  --with-clang \
  --prefix=$PREFIX \
  --libdir=$PREFIX/lib${LIBDIRSUFFIX} \
  --incdir=$PREFIX/include \
  --mandir=$PREFIX/man/man1 \
  --etcdir=$PREFIX/etc/root \
  --docdir=/usr/doc/$PRGNAM-$VERSION \
  --enable-roofit \
  --enable-unuran \
  --disable-builtin-freetype \
  --disable-builtin-ftgl \
  --disable-builtin-glew \
  --disable-builtin-pcre \
  --disable-builtin-zlib \
  --disable-builtin-lzma \
  $GSL_FLAGS \
  $FFTW_FLAGS \
  $QT_FLAGS \
  --enable-shared \
  --build=$ARCH-slackware-linux
```

I am not familiar enough with cmake to know how to do the equivalent. I would prefer a command line option but am open to modifying the CMakeLists.txt file as well.

Comment: For most of these autoconf options it depends how the project you're trying to build named the corresponding CMake option. Even for the autoconf options that have a corresponding standard CMake option (e.g. `--enable-shared` should translate to `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`) it still depends on the project whether they're actually being used. So without the CMakeLists.txt of the project you're trying to build this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @Corristo - The CMakeLists.txt file is 624 lines long. I don't see how to include it without simply copying (which I don't think I should do). How do I share it with the forum?